# How do I find my hostname for my google account?

Tags: macos

Can you help me figure out what my hostname for my google account would be? I'm setting up Fetch (FTP) and I need my hostname for my gmail.

Comment: Err, I'm confused. Why would you want to use Fetch to access your Email account?

Comment: Are you on a Mac, iOS device, or some other "FTP" client?

Comment: Which hostname are you looking for? The SMTP server hostname?

Comment: I am a Macintosh user. Wanting to know how to access my hostname. Is it the IP address or a name??

Comment: @Lila Have you tried your username or your IP?

Comment: I tried IP address. Does not connect. Says it timed out. I don't know what the username would be.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some FTP client you need to connect to their IP Address AFAIK, so with this you can try accessing GMAIL's IP (74.***.235.**) and enter your username and password as other FTP Client is doing.

HTH